# Why I can't copy a whole Ruby on Rails project from a Ubuntu virtual machine to another?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I have a VMware virtual machine with UBuntu 11.04, Apache and MySQL and Ruby on Rails 3.1.
I have done a tutorial in it http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book and I wanted to copy the app to another machine which had the same setup, run "rake db:migrate" and then use the application.

I copied the folder to my host machine (Win 7), opened the second virtual machine and copied the app there.
Well, I see that only some file got copied! Those files which were initially created when you run the "rails new app" command, but not those which were created when doing that tutorial.

I tried to zip up the folder in the virtual machine, copy to host machine, copy again to the second virtual machine. When I unzip it I have the same as above: only the initial app is in that zip, not what I have added later.

Why this happens?? 
I am using a user account, not root account. But I tried using a root account (thinking maybe it's some permission related stuff) and I have the same problem.

How can I make so I can copy an app (with all what's in it) from a machine to another without problems?